# SQL - SUM of one row while DISTINCT in another?

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

I have a table like this

```
| ProjectCode | ProjectCost |
| -------- | -------------- |
| P001    | 12000.00        |
| P001    | 12000.00        |
| P001    | 12000.00        |
| P002    | 4350.50         |   
| P002    | 4350.50         |
| P003    | 13475.35        |
| P003    | 13475.35        |
| P004    | 2750.00         |
```

(And so on)

And I would like the sum of the ProjectCost without it counting the duplicate "ProjectCode" entry. I've tried distinct and group by but can't figure out the correct combination.

I've gotten close with

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT project.projectCost) AS "Total Projects Cost" FROM project
```

but I have P004 and P006 = 2750.00 so the distinct doesn't work

Thanks in advance

Comment: Couls yuo please share the expected output?

Comment: Total Projects Cost = 78,775.73

but I'm getting

Total Projects Cost = 123351.49

Comment: Why are there duplicates in the table in the first place? It looks like you should better fix your data (or the data model?) instead of trying to circumvent issues with some muddle-through query.

Comment: It's because there are more than one person working on the project (in the project table ID 1, ID2 working on P001), I would go back and fix it but I'm at the very end of a group project and it would require re-starting the entire database.

It just seems like something that should be possible to do without rehauling this table

Comment: What do you want to do in case you find different prices for the same project code in the database? Sum up all? Take the least or the greatest value? The average?

Comment: SELECT SUM(ProjectCost) AS TotalCost
FROM     (SELECT DISTINCT ProjectCode , ProjectCost 
                  FROM      project) AS query1

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT SUM(projectCost) AS Total_Projects_Cost
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT projectCode, projectCost FROM project) t
```

Comment: I am using phpMyAdmin and it is coming up with an error for the second select "This type of clause was previously parsed"

Comment: @ScottGibson: the query is valid, this looks like a bug in PHPMyAdmin. Maybe related to this: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12080

Comment: i am still getting the answer as 123351.49 instead of 7877.73

Comment: @ScottGibson: that's surprising. Are you able to reproduce the issue in a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```sql
SELECT SUM(projectCost) AS Total_Projects_Cost
FROM (SELECT projectCode, projectCost FROM project group by projectCode, projectCost) t
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you want?

```
Select sum(projectCost) projectCostSum
from (
Select projectCode, projectCost
from project
group by projectCode,projectCost) a
```

Comment: 4 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "(" at position 52)

Unexpected token. (near "(" at position 52)
This type of clause was previously parsed. (near "Select" at position 56)
Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 136)

Comment: @Scott Gibson: It is weird that you are getting all these errors. The query looks correct (just as the others). Same answer as MDO's by the way. GMS's answer is a little more straight-forward. (We only use `GROUP BY` in combination with aggregation functions usually.)